# CALayer's contentsCenter not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, calayer

I want to increase an image button's touch area, and as I searched, I found a way to use **contentsCenter** property of `CALayer`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410740-contentscenter

The example of the document above shows an image centered inside the layer that can be resized as the size of layer changes, while maintaining the ratio defined in `contentsCenter` property.

But when I used `contentsCenter` property, it just stretches the image's center - `(0.5, 0.5)`.

So I added `contentsGravity` property to .center, but it results in `contentsCenter` property not working.

```
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
    button.center = view.center
    button.backgroundColor = .clear

    let image = UIImage(named: "profileImage")
    button.layer.contents = image?.cgImage
    button.layer.contentsCenter = CGRect(x: 0.25, y: 0.25, width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
    button.layer.contentsGravity = .center
    //button.layer.contentsScale = image?.scale

    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

**How can I make the image center inside a button with insets maintaining ratio?**

Comment: Well, the whole premise of the question is false. The `contentsCenter` property has nothing whatever to do with how to "increase an image button's touch area". So this is what we call an x-y question: you've assumed a false solution to your real problem, and now you're asking why the false solution is false rather than asking about the real problem. I suggest you back this question out and ask instead about how to "increase an image button's touch area".

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `UIButton` Size using the below Code

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```